# How to remove `<a href="file://a>`keep this text`</a>` using sed or perl?

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed, grep

How can I remove all `<a href="file://???">`keep this text`</a>` but not the other `<a></a>` or `</a>` using sed or perl?
Is:

```html
    <p><a class="a" href="file://any" id="b">keep this text</a>, <a href="http://example.com/abc">example.com/abc</a>, more text</p>
```

Should be:

```html
    <p>keep this text, <a href="http://example.com/abc">example.com/abc</a>, more text</p>
```

I have regex like this but it is too greedy and removes all `</a>`

```sh
gsed -E -i 's/<a*href="file:[^>]*>(.+?)<\/a>/\1>/g' file.xhtml
```

Comment: consider updating the question with a more representative set of data; in particular ... you mention `remove all` which implies you may want to remove ***multiple*** entries, so an example that shows multiple entries would be of benefit; also, are you looking to remove ***all*** `file:` entries or just certain ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- OP does not have access to a HTML-centric tool
- remove the `<a href="file:...">`...some_text...`</a>` wrappers leaving just `...some_text...`
- only apply to `file:` entries
- input data does not have a line break/feed in the middle of a `file:` entry

Sample data showing multiple `file:` entries interspersed with some other (nonsensical) entries:

```
$ cat sample.html
<p><a href="https:/google.com">some text</a><a href="file://any" >keep this text</a>, <a href="http://example.com/abc">example.com/abc</a>, more text</p><a href="file://anyother" >keep this text,too</a>, last test</p>
```

One `sed` idea to remove the wrappers for all `file:` entries:

```
sed -E 's|<a[^<>]+file:[^>]+>([^<]+)</a>|\1|g' "${infile}"
```

**NOTE:** perhaps a bit overkill with some of the `[^..]` entries but the key objective is to short circuit `sed's` default greedy matching ...

This leaves:

```
<p><a href="https:/google.com">some text</a>keep this text, <a href="http://example.com/abc">example.com/abc</a>, more text</p>keep this text,too, last test</p>
```

Comment: your code works for me. Thanks! It works with macOS sed and GNU sed and it is the shortest so far.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
sed -E 's,<a[^>]*?href="file://[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>,\1,g'
```

- `<a[^>]*?href="file://[^>]*>` match `<a` + any number of non-`>` (non-greedy) followed by `href="file://` + any number of non-`>` characters followed by `>`
- `([^<]*)` match and capture any number of non-`<` characters
- match on `</a>`

Everything matched is substituted by the capture in `\1` and the ending `g` makes it do the substitution on every occurance on each line.

Examples:

```
$ cat data
<p><a class="a" href="file://any" id="b">keep this text</a>, <a id="file:ex" href="http://example.com/abc">example.com/abc</a>, more text</p>
<p><a href="file://any" class="f">keep this text</a>, <a href="http://example.com/abc">example.com/abc</a>, more text</p>
```

```
$ sed -E 's,<a[^>]*?href="file://[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>,\1,g' < data
<p>keep this text, <a id="file:ex" href="http://example.com/abc">example.com/abc</a>, more text</p>
<p>keep this text, <a href="http://example.com/abc">example.com/abc</a>, more text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works too, however it works only with GNU sed, but it does the job.

Comment: @user3464412 You're welcome - but, it _should_ work with any Posix `sed` unless I'm mistaken. I tried `sed -E --posix` and it gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the case the `<a>` tag consists of the content in multiple lines,
how about a `perl` solution:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's#<a.+?href="?file.+?>(.+?)</a>#$1#gs' file.xhtml
```

- The `-0777` option tells perl to slurp the whole file.
- The `-i` option enables the in-place editing.
- The `s` switch at the end of `s` operator makes a dot match any characters
  including a newline character.
- The regex `.+?` is the non-greedy version of `.+` to enable the shortest match.